# How do I fix my minecraft from doing this at the launcher? (Version 1.8.3)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It keeps saying " Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release" after I try starting up minecraft. I tried to delete Java, and that wouldn't work. I tried to download the version of minecraft where you don't need Java, and it STILL wouldn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incremental CMS is a type of garbage collection method and is configured via the advanced java options in your launcher.
However, that message is only a warning, not an error.  It can safely be ignored for now.

If you insist, look for this string in the advanced java options and remove it.

```
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
```

Note that this is very unlikely to fix your launch problem as the message you saw was only a warning about FUTURE use of this option.

Comment: it doesnt say that. It wont let me remove ANYTHING. I really just need to fix this. Any other suggestions?